# Change Text of an Menu Item

Tags: c++, edit, menuitem

I'm trying to change the Text of a MenuItem created with the winAPI. I tried following:

```
HMENU menu = LoadMenu(_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1)); //getting the Menu

LPWSTR test = L"test";

MENUITEMINFO mii{ sizeof(MENUITEMINFO) };
if (!GetMenuItemInfo(menu, ID_USER_NAME, false, &mii))
{
    return ; // not getting an error here
}

mii.fMask = MIIM_TYPE; // tried with MIIM_TYPE and MIIM_STRING
mii.fType = MFT_STRING;
mii.dwTypeData = test;  

if (!SetMenuItemInfo(menu, ID_USER_NAME, false, &mii))
{
    return; // no error here either
}
DrawMenuBar(_hWnd);
```

But it doesn't work it's is not giving an error either, so I guess I just forgot something ?

Comment: consider adding information about the toolkit you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to get the [handle to the current menu displayed on the window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647640(v=vs.85).aspx) and modify that, instead of loading a menu using `LoadMenu()`.